# SQL Convert Date with UTC Offset and Daylight Savings

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have the following timestamp: `2021-12-03 03:27:12`

I know that this event actually occurred at 10:27PM Eastern Standard Time. I am trying to subtract the UTC offset from this db field and also adjust for daylight savings time. So the date above would subtract 5 hours. This timestamp would subtract 4: 2021-10-19 19:52. I have been messing around with many different SQL functions but have not got this to work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I like to store dates as UTC.  It become a small matter to convert to local time on the client side.  For example in JS, append "UTC" and someone on the East Coast would see 10:27PM while on the West Coast they would see 07:27PM.  Just for fun, pop into your browser's console and try   var d = new Date('2021-12-03 03:27:12 UTC');d

Comment: Problem is: what happens if it was `2021-11-07 01:27:12` there is no way to know if it was DST or normal. You *need* to store the offset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AT TIME ZONE converts a DATETIME to a DATETIMEOFFSET at the specified timezone, or applies the correct offset (including daylight savings) to convert from a DATETIMEOFFSET in one time zone to another.

So

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME = '2021-12-03 03:27:12'
select @DATE 
select @DATE AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
select @DATE AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US Eastern Standard Time'
```

outputs

```
-----------------------
2021-12-03 03:27:12.000

----------------------------------
2021-12-03 03:27:12.000 +00:00

----------------------------------
2021-12-02 22:27:12.000 -05:00
```

So finally to convert a local UTC datetime to a local Eastern Standard datetime:

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME = '2021-12-03 03:27:12'
SELECT cast( @DATE AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US Eastern Standard Time' as datetime );
```

Comment: Amazing. That was it! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For UTC offset you can use this query

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME = '2021-12-03 03:27:12'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET
            -- assuming all servers are on CEST time
            , @DATE AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'));
```

and for Daylight-savings you can use the function in this [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1372/daylight-savings-time-functions-in-sql-server/)