# Converting GMT to EST in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table which stores records for Daylight saving and non-Daylight savings

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp 
(
    ID int,
    IntervalName nvarchar(100),
    StartDate datetime,
    EndDate Datetime,
    offset numeric(5, 2)
)

INSERT INTO #tmp 
VALUES (1, 'EDT', '2022-03-13 07:00:00.000', '2022-11-06 06:00:00.000',-4.00)
INSERT INTO #tmp 
VALUES (2, 'EST', '2022-11-06 06:00:00.000', '2023-03-12 07:00:00.000', -5.00)
```

I have my transactional tables which have `Date` column in the GMT timezone.

```
   ID   DatetimeGMT                  DatetimeLocal  
   ---------------------------------------------------------
   1    2022-11-05 07:00:00.000      2022-11-05 03:00:00.000        
   2    2022-11-10 06:00:00.000      2023-11-10 01:00:00.000
```

Now my `DatetimeLocal` column is calculating the offset hours based on the `DatetimeGMT` column.

The row with `ID = 1` falls under offset -4 and the row with `ID = 2` falls under offset -5.

Is there any suggestion how we can achieve this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70264002/sql-convert-date-with-utc-offset-and-daylight-savings/70264525#70264525

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - It is not changing the Offset for daylight saving as well.

Comment: @AaronBertrand that's why I didn't close it as a dup.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I think it's good to highlight better options for newer (supported!) versions of software, so that people coming later will know.

Comment: So are you using SQL Server 2012? Because you can't possibly be using `AT TIME ZONE` there, since it wasn't introduced until 2 versions later. Please be clear and accurate with version tagging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the offsets all stored in a table like that, then you just need to JOIN to find the correct one.

eg

```
drop table if exists #tmp
drop table if exists #tran
go
CREATE TABLE #tmp 
(
    ID int,
    IntervalName nvarchar(100),
    StartDate datetime,
    EndDate Datetime,
    offset numeric(5, 2)
)

INSERT INTO #tmp 
VALUES (1, 'EDT', '2022-03-13 07:00:00.000', '2022-11-06 06:00:00.000',-4.00)
INSERT INTO #tmp 
VALUES (2, 'EST', '2022-11-06 06:00:00.000', '2023-03-12 07:00:00.000', -5.00)

create table #tran(id int primary key, DateTimeUTC datetime)
insert into #tran(id,DateTimeUTC) values (1,'2022-11-05 07:00:00.000'),(2,'2022-11-10 06:00:00.000')


select t.id, t.DateTimeUTC, dateadd(hour,offset,t.DateTimeUTC) DateTimeLocal, tz.offset
from #tran t
join #tmp tz
  on t.DateTimeUTC >= tz.StartDate
 and t.DateTimeUTC < tz.EndDate
```

outputs

```
id          DateTimeUTC             DateTimeLocal           offset
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------------
1           2022-11-05 07:00:00.000 2022-11-05 03:00:00.000 -4.00
2           2022-11-10 06:00:00.000 2022-11-10 01:00:00.000 -5.00
```

SQL Server 2016 and later have the offsets built-in, so you can write queries like

```
select t.id, 
       t.DateTimeUTC, 
       cast(t.DateTimeUTC at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'EASTERN STANDARD TIME' as datetime) DateTimeLocal
from #tran t
```

Comment: for ID 2 DatetimeLocal is incorrect

Comment: How so?  It's -5 hours offset from DateTimeUTC.  And it matches the value of `cast(cast('2022-11-10 06:00:00.000' as datetime) at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'EASTERN STANDARD TIME' as datetime)`.

Comment: Oh Sorry There is a typo. Your answer is correct